# ERROR Device: (55:37) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.user.length')

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I've set up an array of users in a JSON file, each user being an object containing a username key and a password key. In the login function, I am trying to check whether the   username and password keys entered  correspond  to one  of the  valid username/password pairs given in the objects of the   list. If it does, it takes the user to the Dashboard page, otherwise it alerts to indicate login     failure. However, it comes up with this error:

> Device: (55:37) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.user.length')

What am I doing wrong?

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import * as userdata from '../data/users.json';

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.user = userdata.username;

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  handleUsername = text => {
    this.setState({ username: text });
  };

  handlePassword = text => {
    this.setState({ password: text });
  };

  login = (username,password) => {
    let found = false

    for (var i=0; i<this.user.length; i++) {
      if (this.user[i].username == username && this.user[i].password == password) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('My Dashboard');
    } else {
      alert ('Incorrect username/password')
    }
  };
```

JSON file

```
[
  {
    "name": "Andreea Mitel",
    "id": 1,
    "username": "andreeam",
    "password": "aaa",
    "email address": "andreea@uwl.co.uk"
  },
  {
    "name": "Aniko Kovacs",
    "id": 2,
    "username": "anikok",
    "password": "bbb",
    "email address": "aniko@uwl.co.uk"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Ana Stetco",
    "id": 3,
    "username": "anas",
    "password": "ccc",
    "email address": "ana@uwl.co.uk"
  },
  {
    "name": "Gulden Belli",
    "id": 4,
    "username": "guldenb",
    "password": "ddd",
    "email address": "gulden@uwl.co.uk"
  }, 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You declaring `this.users` wrongly (line 7).

Edit: It's recommended import json file using this way:

`import userdata from '../data/users.json';` (w/o using wildcard)

Please, try the fixed code:

```js
import userdata from '../data/users.json';

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();

this.user = userdata; // <- fix

this.state = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
};
 }

handleUsername = text => {
this.setState({ username: text });
};

handlePassword = text => {
this.setState({ password: text });
};

login = (username,password) => {
let found = false

for (var i=0; i<this.user.length; i++) {
if (this.user[i].username == username && this.user[i].password == password) {
  found = true;
  break;
}
}
if (found) {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('My Dashboard');
} else {
  alert ('Incorrect username/password')
}
};
```

Comment: I don't get the error anymore, so thank you for that, however it comes up with incorrect username/password even if it's correct....

Comment: Not sure how :D